# I cannot pass the data from my text file to my queue

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue, file-handling

I am creating a program that will store the data from my textfile and enqueue it to my queue. I have already created a function for it, however it doesn't store the data into my queue.

Here is my function to get the data from the textfile and insert it into my queue:

```
void TextToQueue() {
    Queue<Information> link; //Connecting my Queue to my structure called Information
    Information TextInfo; //Information is a structure containing string Name, Address, and ID
    Temp_File t; //Temp_File is a structure containing string data and type.
    fstream FILE;
    int i = 0;
    char delimiter = ':';
    char delimiter1 = '\n';
    FILE.open("Sample.txt", ios::in);
    if (FILE.is_open()) {
        while (getline(FILE, t.type, delimiter) && getline(FILE, t.data, delimiter1)) {
            if (i == 0) { 
                TextInfo.Name = t.data; //The data inside my t.data will be stored in TextInfo.Name
                i++;
            }
            else if (i == 1) {
                TextInfo.Address = t.data; //The data inside my t.data will be stored in TextInfo.Address
                i++;
            }
            else if (i == 2) {
                TextInfo.ID = t.data; //The data inside my t.data will be stored in TextInfo.ID
                link.push(TextInfo); //Pushing or Enqueuing the data to my queue
                i = 0; //the value of i will become zero again to repeat the whole process whenever there are a lot of data inside the file.
            }
        }
        FILE.close();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "File is not open.";
    }
}
```

Here is my push function to store the data to the queue. The push function works whenever I insert new data to my textfile, however I think the problem is within the TextToQueue function:

```
template <class T>
void Queue<T>::push(T data) {
    Queue* tmp = new Queue;
    tmp->value = data;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    if (!front) {
        rear = tmp;
        front = tmp;
    }
    else {
        rear->next = tmp;
        rear = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: `link.push(C_Info_LList)`... When and where do you define and initialize the `C_Info_LList` variable? Why don't you push `TextInfo` that you do initialize in the function?

Comment: Oh sorry. Forgot to fully edit my variables. Hold on. I changed my variables names when I posted this question.

Comment: This is one reason you should try to create a proper [mcve] that you try yourself to make sure it replicates the problem before posting.

Comment: Another thing, you define the *local* variable `link` inside the `TextToQueue` function. The life-time of this variable will end when the function ends, and all the data you push to it will be lost. Are you supposed to return the queue, or perhaps modify a member or global variable with the name `link`?

Comment: I supposed to use the function at the start of the program so that whenever there's data inside the textfile. It will automatically push it into the queue. I have a class called Queue. Hold on lemme add the queue class sorry.

Comment: We don't need the full class. Instead think about when and where you define your `link` variable. As I said it's a ***local*** variable inside the function. Once the function returns the variable `link` disappears and all nodes you added to the queue will also disappear. Perhaps you need to take a step back and refresh about variable scope and life-time?

Comment: _"however it doesn't store the data into my queue"_ How do you know it? It's not possible to access the local queue from outside the function. Are you shadowing a global variable `link`? How do you access your queue? You can see multiple question in the comments. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I try to pop the front of the queue when I start the program since the TextToQueue functions starts at the execution of the program so I assume that there will be data in my queue already. However when I try to pop, it says that the queue doesn't have any data. My pop function works though whenever I insert data then tries to pop it.

Comment: Please show us the code for _"I try to pop the front of the queue"_. It looks like you have two different queues. One queue is filled with data and the other queue is read.

Comment: It makes no sense to attempt to pop a queue when you haven't even added anything to it. It is properly initialized with all pointers set to `nullptr` (or `0`)? And *which* queue to you attempt to pop? It can't be the one inside the `TextToQueue` function, since it can only be done from inside that function. You probably have multiple different and distinct queues with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the local scoping of the loop and if statements. Each time you assign an attribute to `Information` the constructor is invoked. Solution would be to use a `auto TextInfo = new Information` constructor, push it, then reassign `TextInfo` to a new object. Just would have to account for destroying the created objects. Or you could push `TextInfo` to the queue, then just modify attributes and push a new blank one on the final clause.

Answer (score 1):

`link` is a local variable that's not returned. You can't access it from outside the function. One solution to your problem is to pass a queue by reference to `TextToQueue`, fill it inside the function and read it outside the function:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T>
struct Queue {
    T value;
    Queue* front;
    Queue* rear;
    Queue* next;
    void push(T data);
};

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::push(T data) {
    Queue* tmp = new Queue;
    tmp->value = data;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    if (!front) {
        rear = tmp;
        front = tmp;
    }
    else {
        rear->next = tmp;
        rear = tmp;
    }
}

struct Information {
    std::string ID;
    std::string Name;
    std::string Address;
};
struct Temp_File {
    std::string type;
    std::string data;
};

void TextToQueue(Queue<Information> &link) {
    Information TextInfo; //Information is a structure containing string Name, Address, and ID
    Temp_File t; //Temp_File is a structure containing string data and type.
    std::fstream FILE("Sample.txt", std::ios::in);
    int i = 0;
    char delimiter = ':';
    char delimiter1 = '\n';
    if (FILE.is_open()) {
        while (getline(FILE, t.type, delimiter) && getline(FILE, t.data, delimiter1)) {
            if (i == 0) { 
                TextInfo.Name = t.data; //The data inside my t.data will be stored in TextInfo.Name
                i++;
            }
            else if (i == 1) {
                TextInfo.Address = t.data; //The data inside my t.data will be stored in TextInfo.Address
                i++;
            }
            else if (i == 2) {
                TextInfo.ID = t.data; //The data inside my t.data will be stored in TextInfo.ID
                link.push(TextInfo); //Pushing or Enqueuing the data to my queue
                std::cout << "push\n";
                i = 0; //the value of i will become zero again to repeat the whole process whenever there are a lot of data inside the file.
            }
        }
        FILE.close();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "File is not open.";
    }
}

int main() {
    Queue<Information> link; //Connecting my Queue to my structure called Information
    TextToQueue(link);
    std::cout << "Data: \n";
    std::cout << '"' << link.front->value.ID << "\"\n";
    std::cout << '"' << link.front->value.Name << "\"\n";
    std::cout << '"' << link.front->value.Address << "\"\n";
}
```

File:

```
id:ID
name:Name
address:Address
```

Output:

```
Data: 
"Address"
"ID"
"Name"
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! However, I have a question. This might be a dumb question, but it will help me a lot in the future to understand it better. Why do I need to pass it by a reference? What's the difference when passing it by a reference compare to a non-reference?

Comment: @Richard Passing by value creates a copy and wouldn't solve your problem. You would still have two distinct queues, one with data inside the function and one without data outside the function.